# ConstraintView disturbs on showing keyboard

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I went through different solutions from stackoverflow and other websites but still unsolved. When keyboard appears, the radio buttons go at the top of editText.

[image]

In onCreate Method of MainActivity class, I wrote this line:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
```

In Android Manifest.xml, I added a line in Activity:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
 android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
>
```

Following is the acitivtiy_main.xml:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/azadRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="آزاد"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qafiaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="قافیہ"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sabiqaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="سابقہ"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="Finder"
        android:text="Finder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="339dp"
        android:layout_height="266dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Post the XML for the layout. Are all views constrained vertically and horizontally?

Comment: i edited... check plz

Comment: yes all objects nodes are linked to each other and left, right, up, down borders.

Comment: OK. What do you want it to look like? A lot of your widgets have fixed sizes so may they may not fit into the reduced area when the keyboard shows. I assume that the layout looks OK without the keyboard. Try `adjustPan` instead of `adjustResize`.

Comment: I tried adjustResize and adjustPan, it didn't work. I want it to look like the screenshot I provided. see the label "SHould look like this" in screenshot. I want radiobuttons beneath the editText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add nestedScrollView from top and end of your xml. like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="368dp"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/listView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/azadRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="آزاد"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/qafiaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="قافیہ"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/sabiqaRadio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:text="سابقہ"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </RadioGroup>


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="36dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:onClick="Finder"
        android:text="Finder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.555"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="339dp"
        android:layout_height="266dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `EditText` has a non-zero height (wrap_content), and is constrained to the top of the parent.

Your `ListView` has a fixed height (266dp), and is constrained to the bottom of the parent.

Your `RadioGroup` has a fixed height (47dp), and is constrained to be between the `EditText` and the `ListView`.

Consider what will happen when the available height (the height of the parent) is less than 266dp + 47dp + EditText height. Even simpler, consider what will happen if the available height is less than 266dp.

In these cases, the top of the `ListView` will actually be *above* the bottom of the `EditText`. This will "pull" the `RadioGroup` in opposite directions, and it will wind up overlaying itself on top of the `EditText` and the `ListView`.

There's no quick fix to solve this. Probably what you want to do is change how everything is sized and constrained. I'd recommend:

- Leave the EditText the way it is
- Change the RadioGroup to only be constrained to the bottom of the EditText
- Change the ListView to have 0dp height, and constrain its top to the bottom of the RadioGroup and its bottom to the bottom of the parent

This will wind up giving all the "extra" space to the `ListView`.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    ...>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText"
        ...>

        <!-- ... -->

    </RadioGroup>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        .../>

    <Button
        .../>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```